# WLAN LED constantly on (T410, Xubuntu)

Tags: wireless, xubuntu

I find it rather annoying, that my WLAN indicator LED stopped working on Xubuntu 14.04. Its on no matter what I do to the interface, i.e. disable it. It also does not blink on activity. 
The only way it does -anything- is killing the hardware switch, then it turns off.

On Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 it reacts fine with being on when wifi is enablend, being off when its disabled and blinking when there is a transfer.
How can i get this to work? Its an Intel Centrino 6200AGN.

greetings!

---

my /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi led_mode=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi led_mode=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
modprobe -r iwldvm
modprobe iwlwifi
exit
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.

If '=1' doesn't help, edit the file to try the other options that you can find here:

```
modinfo iwlwifi
```

> parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off),
>   2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)

Edit the file in question:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to try 2 or 3 as the parameter. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doenst change anything :(
The LED is on even with interface down and rfkilled.
I've stumbled accross this led_mode, is there any documentation?

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: News: I get the feeling, that my iwlwifi.conf @ /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf is completely ignored. I've tried every option followed by a reboot and it doesn't change anything. Actual content in first post.\\

I've removed my Gobi WWAN for testing purpose (on Windows, WWAN and WLAN share the same LED) and without the WWAN it reacts to the WLAN state as in mode 1 (independent of the iwlwifi.conf). Its on for WLAN activated and off for deactivated. But it wont blink on transfer.\\
Since it works on Ubuntu 14.04, is there any chance for cross-referencing any useful information?

Comment: Information is sparse: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=led_mode What is the driver for the WWAN? Maybe there is a parameter we can manipulate there.

Comment: Bad news, my memory was bad :( The LED does not work on either Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. Its just always on.\\
For WWAN I've got a Gobi 2000 and use the gobi-loader to wrap the proprietary driver files. Mobile Network performs good. (But also doesn't blink)

Comment: I regret that I have no further suggestions. FWIW, I have the same laptop and wireless card, but no WWAN, and my LED works as expected. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.